# Exclude schema from deploying with Octopus

Tags: octopus-deploy, octopus

It's there any way that i can specify a schema name that i don't want to be deployed with Octopus Deploy? I have a Visual Studio database project that has a schema generated automatically (with tables and stored procedures). I don't want this to be deployed. 
I can't delete it directly from project because it verifies the dependencies at build time.

Comment: Is there 1 dacpac in your NuGet package? Maybe you could restructure your solution so the dependencies are in a different project and your dacpac only includes what is required for deployment.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing specific to Octopus to do this however [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23550081/how-to-make-dacpac-update-only-one-schema) covers the options.

If you're using a [custom script step](https://octopus.com/docs/deploying-applications/custom-scripts) or a [community step template](https://library.octopusdeploy.com/step-template/actiontemplate-sql-deploy-dacpac) to deploy your dacpac, you can provide additional parameters to control what is deployed.