# DACPAC - How to deploy one particular schema

Tags: sql-server, continuous-integration, dacpac, sqlpackage

I've been looking to find ways to deploy one particular schema (Schema B) from database (Schema A, Schema B, Schema c..)  using dacpac and sqlpackage.exe.

I found this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23550081/how-to-make-dacpac-update-only-one-schema) but looks like the links on it have been archived. also found out to put this parameter in sqlpackage.exe cmd `DropObjectsNotInSource = false` but still both schema are getting deployed. can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out this can be done using this [DeploymentContributorFilterer](https://github.com/GoEddie/DeploymentContributorFilterer).

Put the AgileSqlClub.SqlPackageFilter.dll file into the same folder as SqlPackage.exe, and add these commmand line parameters to your deployment:

```
/p:AdditionalDeploymentContributors=AgileSqlClub.DeploymentFilterContributor /p:AdditionalDeploymentContributorArguments="SqlPackageFilter=IgnoreSchema(**SchemaA**)"
```